# Function addnode for different linked list structures

Tags: c

Is there a way to write a single function ( addnode ) for different structures? I've this scenario:

```
typedef struct linkedlist_a *ptr_a;
typedef struct linkedlist_a
{
    /* content */
    ptr_a next;
} listA;

typedef struct linkedlist_b *ptr_b;
typedef struct linkedlist_b
{
    /* content */
    ptr_b next;
} listB;

listA *listA_addnode( listA *head, listA *node )
{
    listA *temp = head;
    if( temp == NULL )
    {
        temp = node;
    }
    else if( temp -> next == NULL )
    {
        temp -> next = node;
    }
    else
    {
        while( temp -> next ) temp = temp -> next;
        temp -> next = node;        
    }

    return head;
}


listB *listB_addnode( listB *head, listB *node )
{
    listB *temp = head;
    if( temp == NULL )
    {
        temp = node;
    }
    else if( temp -> next == NULL )
    {
        temp -> next = node;
    }
    else
    {
        while( temp -> next ) temp = temp -> next;
        temp -> next = node;        
    }

    return head;
}
```

If there's two structuress is ok for me write two function but in case I've more than 2, how can I do?

Comment: Are you declaring two different linked lists to hold different types?

Comment: if you call the addnode() function on an empty list, it won't work - you need to change the head to point to the newly allocated node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having different `struct`s that represent a linked list a possible solution would be to have single linked list `struct` that has `void*` member for data. This would allow a single `add_node()` function with a slightly different signature.

For example:

```
struct linked_node
{
    void* data;
    struct linked_node* next;
};

void add_node(struct linked_node** a_head, void* a_data)
{
    struct linked_node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    new_node->data = a_data;
    new_node->next = 0;
    if (!*a_head)
    {
        *a_head = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

There is a danger with this approach, namely the correct interpretation the `data` member. However, with care this approach would meet your requirements.

Example use (error checking omitted):

```
struct data_x { int i; char c; };
struct data_y { char* s; };

struct linked_node* list_x = 0;
struct data_x* dx = malloc(sizeof(*dx));
dx->i = 4;
dx->c = 'a';

add_node(&list_x, dx);

if (list_x)
{
    struct data_x* x = list_x->data;
    printf("x.i=%d x.c=%c\n", x->i, x->c);
}

struct linked_node* list_y = 0;
struct data_y* dy = malloc(sizeof(*dy));
dy->s = "hello";

add_node(&list_y, dy);

if (list_y)
{
    struct data_y* y = list_y->data;
    printf("y.s=%s\n", y->s);
}
```

See online demo http://ideone.com/iZO8h.

Comment: The "data" can be a wrapper struct which embeds the value and type information which will allow you to infer and cast at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do this is with a macro assuming your linking elements are called the same (`next` is present in all types you wish to pass there).

GNU style code ahead: `-std=gnu98` or above

```
#define addnode( head, node ) ({\
    typeof(head) _head = (head);\
    typeof(node) _node = (node);\
    if( _head == NULL )\
    {\
        _head = _node;\
    }\
    else\
    {\
        while( _head -> next ) _head = _head -> next;\
        _head -> next = _node;        \
    }\
    \
    _head;\
})
```

This is pretty bad programming style though